# Обработка нажатия кнопки Вверх

Tags: android, android-intent

Имеется следующий код:

```
package asus.example.com.fitnessapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class ProgramActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView imageView;
    private TextView textView;
    private final String PROGRAM="PROGRAM";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_program);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.text);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.p1);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar!=null){
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
        String path = getIntent().getStringExtra(PROGRAM);
        readFromFile(path);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.home:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    private void readFromFile(String path){
        byte[] buffer = null;
        InputStream inputStream;
        try {
            inputStream = getAssets().open(path);
            int size = inputStream.available();
            buffer = new byte[size];
            inputStream.read(buffer);
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String data = new String(buffer);
        textView.setText(data);
    }

}
```

Однако почему-то по нажатию кнопки вверх, выхода в MainActivity не происходит, хотя в то же время в другой активности, где прописан такой же метод, все исправно работает (вот код):

```
package asus.example.com.fitnessapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class ArticleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String article = "ARTICLE";
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_article);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
        String path = getIntent().getStringExtra(article);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.article);
        readFromFile(path);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.home:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                return true;
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    private void readFromFile(String path){
        byte[] buffer = null;
        InputStream is;
        try {
            is = getAssets().open(path);
            int size = is.available();
            buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String data = new String(buffer);
        textView.setText(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Что за кнопка вверх? Если ты про R.id.home, то у тебя там вообще не выход прописан а открытие нового экрана MainActivit.

Comment: @yno7, так да. Я таким образом реализую выход в родительскую активность

Comment: И в коде снизу не открывается MainActivity?

Comment: А не пробовали писать "android.R.id.home"? (хотя вообще так и надо писать)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужно возвращаться обратно , то вам можно воспользоваться а
точнее переопределить метод

public void onBackPressed()

и добавить ему например `finish();`

примерно так:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    this.finish();
}
```

и далее везде ссылаться на него:

```
switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
```

а еще можно воспользоваться тулбаром и возвращаться кнопкой "назад" на нем:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("my title");
        Drawable drawable = toolbar.getNavigationIcon();
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(drawable);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(drawable);
    }

 @Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Нет смысла переопределять onBackPressed чтоб написать там finish. Этот метод и так имеет в конечном итоге такую реализацию.

Comment: тогда можно ссылаться без переопределения используя оператор `super`